# I would like to capture only ID with autocomplete with POJO Pimefaces

Tags: primefaces

I need to capture the ID only instead of object. Here is my code snippet:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Buscar Aval:" for="aval"/>
<p:autoComplete id="aval" value="#{tipocambioBean.tipoc.modelo}"
        completeMethod="#{anexoBean.filtrarAval}" var="aval"
        itemLabel="#{aval.nombres}" itemValue="#{aval.idanexo}">
    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{anexoBean.anexos}"/>
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@form" />                        
</p:autoComplete>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it.
only I need to do is to remove the converter and change `itemValue`, Here is my code snippet:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Buscar Aval:" />
<p:autoComplete value="#{tipocambioBean.tipoc.modelo}"
        completeMethod="#{anexoBean.filtrarAval}" var="aval"
        itemLabel="#{aval.nombres}" itemValue="#{aval.idanexo}">                                
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@form" />                        
</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: Question:why did you add a converter in the first place?

Comment: @Kukeltje Because in the first place I capture a object, and the second place I capture a Primary Key. Regards.
Sorry for my bad english